# Does a point end if the volleyball hits the net?

Tags: rules, volleyball

While score keeping a game of volleyball, one of the plays confused me: the ball hit the net and went over, but it still counted as a point. Is this the correct ruling?

Answer (score 2):

As you've probably realised by now, a ball hitting the net (within the side bands) does not end the point. See Rule 10.2 of the [FIVB rules](https://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf):

> While crossing the net, the ball may touch it